# How to implement Speech To Text highlighter like Build A Module site?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, speech-to-text

Actually I came across through a site for Drupal called [Build A Module](http://buildamodule.com/video/introduction-welcome-to-buildamodule-a-quick-message-from-chris-shattuck-the-creator-of-buildamodule#viewing) and here is a screen shot for which I am talking about an implementation.

[image]

From the Screen you can see a Highlighted Rectangle with Red color shows that whatever being spoken by Tutorial Representative is being highlighted in the Right Panel just besides it.

It's a really very very great concept.

1. What does it call?
2. How can we implement it?
3. How to implement in PHP?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One idea is to create a timestamped transcript of the audio and then just have a script that highlights the correct text for a given timestamp interval. Check [subrip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubRip) for some ideas.

Comment: It's not clear that speech is being decoded here - as Jorge says, it's probably a manual transcript. You can do the highlighting with JavaScript.

Comment: @halfer, Actually when you see at the link which I specified above, You will see that Representative speaking and it's related Texts are bring highlighted. So How about Manual Transcript? like you suggested

Comment: @JorgeIsraelPeña, about a link which you've specified say that it extracts `subtitle` texts from video which has `subtitle`. But in this case it's not.

Comment: @NullPointer The relevant part of the link I provided is the [timestamped transcript file structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubRip#SubRip_.28.srt.29_structure_examples). What I'm saying is that I'm assuming that the site you're talking about created their own such transcript, and are doing the highlighting with javascript based on this transcript. If that still isn't clear: I don't think it's automatically converting audio to text and then highlighting it, my guess is that the text was manually created with lines timestamped with the time at which they occur in the audio.

Comment: @JorgeIsraelPeña, Yes. You're totally right. I looked it with DevTool (F12) in chrome and found that Texts are manually written and it's coordinating with Speech and based on it, it highlights text using jQuery+CSS. So I would like to know about How it coordinate with speech or How can we set manual transcript like settings?

Comment: You don't coordinate it with speech - you coordinate it with time. How you implement your data structure is up to you - maybe hold the text as one long string, and then keep an array that pairs "seconds elapsed" with "string index". For greatest accuracy you could do this with every word, but in general for text-to-audio (e.g. subtitles, karaoke, etc) every 6-7 words is fine. For clarity, this timestamp-to-index is not derived automatically, you need to add that yourself - maybe by reading out aloud and using a stopwatch lap function to obtain the data?